# Ionic Scroll Bar in android device is not visible

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I have tried everything to show Ionic scrollbar on my android device but not able to do. I can see in browser but in device it is not simply visible.

Comment: can you your index file.

Comment: I didnt get you, Ajinkya